# List in Android: Rename duplicated items

Tags: java, android

I want to create lists as follows:

- list-item
- list-item-1
- list-item-2
- list-myitem
- list-myItem-1

As above with *list-item*, if the item's name is the same in next row, then it will add the suffix `1`.

[image]

like this
done upto this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBqeq.png)

Comment: What is exactly your question? Are you asking for direction to implement what you're describing, or you're having issue with your code that doesn't do the right thing?

Comment: i want a direction ,how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you want to ask how to implement this. The most simple solution I can think of is using a `Map<String, Int>` to keep track of the item name. Your code will look somewhat like this:

`final Map<String, Integer> listNameMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

When displaying a list item name, you'll do:

```
final String displayedName;
if (listNameMap.containsKey(name)) {
   Integer newValue = listNameMap.get(name).intValue() + 1;
   listNameMap.put(name, newValue);
   displayedName = name + "-" + String.valueOf(newValue);
} else {
   listNameMap.put(name, 0);
   displayedName = name;
}
// then use the displayedName to display
```

Comment: its not displaying suffix,always executing else part.can u suggest me any other way .thanks

Comment: Could you print all the `name` and the `listNameMap` while looping through your list? I can't think of a reason why the above code doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

i have tried with sample data  and below solution worked for me.But there can more efficient solution also. This solution doesn't require ordering of data.

```
List<String> parent =new  ArrayList<String>();

    parent.add("R");
    parent.add("I");
    parent.add("S");

    parent.add("R");
    parent.add("I");
    parent.add("S");
    parent.add("R");
    parent.add("I");
    parent.add("S");
    parent.add("R");
    parent.add("R");
    parent.add("I");

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(parent);
    ArrayList<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
    valuesList .addAll(set);



    Log.d("ValueListWithoutDuplicates",valuesList.size()+"");
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<valuesList.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<parent.size();j++){
            if(valuesList.get(i).equals(parent.get(j))){
                if(counter==0){
                    counter++;
                }else {
                    parent.set(j,parent.get(j)+String.valueOf(counter));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }


        counter=0;
    }

   for(int i=0;i<parent.size();i++){
       Log.d("final value",parent.get(i)+"");
   }
```